# Remove delete option on FiIleZilla Server

Tags: filezilla, user-management

Is there a way to remove or grey out the *Delete* option from the list in the screenshot below, so that no user can delete files from the server or client?

Here is the user list; I want to remove those options:

[image: screenshot]

I have many users on the server and adding all the accounts is quite unrealistic and tough, so I want to disable it so no one can check it.

Comment: I don't know if you can disable these options in general, but you can edit the XML user file directly and then start Filezilla with the `/reload-config` switch

Comment: The safest option is to control deletions on the server in the user permissions: then it won't matter which FTP client they use.

Comment: @AFH I have tried it, but they can still delete files, I want to let them delete thier files on server not other users.

Comment: @acejavelin please explain more

Comment: @Harsh The user database is an XML file, just add users without the options your referencing manually and restart the server with the reload-config option. I haven't done this specifically, but the file is pretty straight forward if you have a basic understanding of xml

Comment: @acejavelin the thing is there are about 20-50users in the server, and adding them in XML one by one, with each in different directory is not really practical.

Comment: @Harsh You don't have a spreadsheet or something that you can import? A little copy, paste, and tweak can go a long way. But I just threw it out there, the Filezilla-project.org forums have tons of discussions on similar issues and editing, it might be useful. I didn't provide an answer, only a comment, because I wasn't going to all the research for you, just hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand your response: you say you want to remove the **Delete** options from FileZilla, which would prevent deletion of their own files. To allow user-only deletions on the server, you can give the users two directories: their own with full permissions, and everyone's with delete prevented.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such configuration.

It won't help you anyway. If the users have permissions to modify the FileZilla Server settings in the GUI, they must be able to edit its XML configuration file (otherwise the admin interface won't be able to save it). So hiding some GUI options won't really help, as the users can edit the XML file directly.

Though the FileZilla Server is open source. So you can build a custom version fit for your needs.

Though way easier would be, not to allow users to mess with the FileZilla Server configuration. Rather create a simple script that the user runs, enter his/her credentials and the script adds an entry to the FileZilla Server XML configuration file with the desired permissions.

Comment: Actually I do not wnat them to delete anything via Filezilla Server, thats why i want that option removed. I just want them to Read & Write the files, not Delete,.

Comment: OK, so do not check the "Delete" permissions. I actually do not understand your screenshot. You do not have any users configured. So how do they log in?

Comment: It is a vanilla server, I have not added yet, There are 20-40users on the server and they add account themself, thats why i want to disable "Delete" Option fully, so no one can select it.

Comment: First, how could we know that the user add themselves? Second, that approach is insane. And anyway, if they can login to the server, they have a probably full access to the file system. So what's the point of preventing them using FTP to delete files, if they can do the same directly on the server?

Comment: They cannot access crucial files or other users files within the server, that is why i want to disable Delete option.

Comment: But if they can modify the FileZilla Server settings in the GUI, they must be able to edit its XML configuration file (otherwise the admin interface won't be able to save it). So hiding some GUI options won't really help.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: That actually makes sense, i will try to create a script :)
It would be much easeir in Linux though...